# Keras: ValueError: No data provided for "input_1". Need data for each key

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I am using the keras functional API with input images of dimension (224, 224, 3). I have the following model using the functional API, although a similar problem seems to arise with sequential models:

```
input = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3,))
shared_layers = Dense(16)(input)
model = KerasModel(input=input, output=shared_layers)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', metrics='accuracy'])
```

I am calling `model.fit_generator` where my generator has

```
yield ({'input_1': image}, {'output': classification})
```

`image` is the input (224, 224, 3) image and `classification` is in {-1,1}.

On fitting the model, I get an error

```
ValueError: No data provided for "dense_1". Need data for each key in: ['dense_1']
```

One strange thing is that if I switch the `input_1` target of the dict to `dense_1`, the error switches to missing an input for `input_1`, but goes back to missing `dense_1` if both keys are in the data generator.

This happens whether I call `fit_generator` or get batches from the generator and call `train_on_batch`.

Does anyone know what's going on? From what I can tell, this should be the same as given in [the documentation](https://keras.io/models/model/) although with a different input size.

```
Full traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pymask.py", line 303, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "pymask.py", line 285, in main
    keras.callbacks.ProgbarLogger()
  File "/home/danielunderwood/virtualenvs/keras/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1557, in fit_generator
    class_weight=class_weight)
  File "/home/danielunderwood/virtualenvs/keras/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1314, in train_on_batch
    check_batch_axis=True)
  File "/home/danielunderwood/virtualenvs/keras/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1029, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='model input')
  File "/home/danielunderwood/virtualenvs/keras/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 52, in standardize_input_data
    str(names))
ValueError: No data provided for "input_1". Need data for each key in: ['input_1']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was due to me misunderstanding how the keras outputs work. The layer specified by the `output` argument to `Model` requires the output from the data. I misunderstood that the `output` key in the data dictionary automatically goes to the layer specified by the `output` argument.

Comment: I am having the same problem, but could not understand your answer. Could you please point me out at the modifications you made?

Comment: @AntonioSesto I hate to say it, but I'm not entirely sure of what my answer meant either. I looked back through git and slack logs and wasn't able to find too much. I _think_ the issue was that I was using `'output'` as a key that I thought would be there, but the key instead had to be the layer of the output, which would have the key `'shared_layers'` instead. For what it's worth, I also ended up switching to tensorflow with tensorlayer rather than keras due to issues with my particular model in this case.

Answer (score 15):

I encountered this error on 3 cases (In R):

1. The input data does not have the same dimension as was declared in the first layer
2. The input data includes missing values
3. The input data is not a matrix (for example, a data frame)

Please check all of the above.

Maybe this code in R can help:

```
library(keras)

#The network should identify the rule that a row sum greater than 1.5 should yield an output of 1

my_x=matrix(data=runif(30000), nrow=10000, ncol=3)
my_y=ifelse(rowSums(my_x)>1.5,1,0)
my_y=to_categorical(my_y, 2)

model = keras_model_sequential()
layer_dense(model,units = 2000, activation = "relu", input_shape = c(3))
layer_dropout(model,rate = 0.4)
layer_dense(model,units = 50, activation = "relu")
layer_dropout(model,rate = 0.3)
layer_dense(model,units = 2, activation = "softmax")

compile(model,loss = "categorical_crossentropy",optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(),metrics = c("accuracy"))

history <- fit(model,  my_x, my_y, epochs = 5, batch_size = 128, validation_split = 0.2)

evaluate(model,my_x, my_y,verbose = 0)

predict_classes(model,my_x)
```

Comment: It was #3 for me *facepalm*

Comment: This is an excellent answer, not only for the list but for the example. #3 in my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I have encountered this issue as well and none of the above mentioned answers worked.  According to the keras [documentation](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) you can pass the arguments either as a dictionary like that:

```
model.fit({'main_input': headline_data, 'aux_input': additional_data},
      {'main_output': labels, 'aux_output': labels},
      epochs=50, batch_size=32)
```

or as a list like that:

```
model.fit([headline_data, additional_data], [labels, labels],
      epochs=50, batch_size=32)
```

The dictionary version didn't work for me with keras version 2.0.9. I have used the list version as a workaround for now.

Answer (score 2):

```
yield ({'input_1': image}, {'output': classification})
```

Replace `output` with `dense_1`.
It will work.

Comment: what yield ? where yield ? how yield ? Your answer needs improvement